# Multivalued attribute grouping in SOLR

Tags: solr

I came across a problem where one of my column is multivalued. eg: value can be (11,22) (11,33) (11,55) , (22,44) , (22,99)

I want to perform a grouping operation that will yield:

- 11 : count 3
- 22 : count 3
- 33 : 1
- 44 : 1
- 55 : 1
- 99 : 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One indirect way to achieve this is to copy all the values corresponding to this field with space or some other character  between them in a text field and then tokenize this field with that character(using `whitespace tokenizer` in case of spaces). Then you can use group by and I believe that this should work.

Comment: how can we do this. i am a newbie :-(
can you give me an example

Comment: i believe that you must be using some script to do solr indexing..let's say the field described by you here is `kid_multivaued`, so what I mean is that you create another field while indexing, let's say `kid_combined` with all the values of `kid_multivalued` copied to `kid_combined` with a whitespace between them so if `kid_multivalued` is `(11,55)` kid_combined will become `11 55` and this kid_combined should be tokenized using whitesapce tokenizer, which can be set  inside its field type definition, in schema.xml, then if you try to group by using this field,you can get desired results

Comment: can you please provide me with link for solr documentation.
i am not able to find any good online info

Comment: well if you want to start to learn solr. I don't think that there is a better documentation than [solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/).... try to go to schema section for having more clarity on this...

Answer (score 4):

Multivalued field cannot be grouped in Solr as yet.

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Known_Limitations) :-

> Support for grouping on a multi-valued field has not yet been
>   implemented.

Comment: It's been a while, does Solr 4.8.x supports this feature??